# plural forms - family names

Tags: plural-forms, proper-nouns

Which phrase is correct?

> This is the Brown family

vs

> This is the Brown**s** family

(where Brown is a surname)

Or both variants are correct when we are talking about the whole family? This question has arosen because in some student's books I saw one variant, in other ones - another variant.

Thank you in advance for your answers and explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct form is "This is the **Brown** family" or "This is the **Ivanov** family."  When you're using a name like that, you don't pluralize it; the name is of the whole family.

But you say "These are the **Browns**" or "These are the **Ivanovs**" if you're not using the word "family", because now you are talking about more than one "Brown" or more than one "Ivanov".